# What is the best Scala library for AWS DynamoDB

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am writing a scala app that needs to interact with DynamoDB. I see many open-sources out there. Some examples are:

https://github.com/piotrga/async-dynamo

https://github.com/bizreach/aws-dynamodb-scala

https://github.com/seratch/AWScala

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-scala

https://dwhjames.github.io/aws-wrap/index.html

Or perhaps it's better to use the official AWS SDK in Java?
Anyone have any experience with one of the above open-sources?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Alpakka project, which provides a DynamoDB [connector](http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/dynamodb.html). Alpakka connectors are built on [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/index.html) and provide a way to interact with various technologies and protocols in a [reactive](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) way.

Comment: How well does it fit into a ETL app? Like a play-framework CRUD app, where your normally just reading or updating 1 row. I like akka-streams but I think of it more for bulk jobs. Maybe Im wrong about that, akka-http is backed by streams.